# In Perl using Mojo::DOM in XML mode, how do I match on contents of subtags?

Tags: xml, perl, dom, mojolicious

I have the following XML:

```
<Product>
  ...
    <TitleDetail>
      <TitleType>01</TitleType>
      <TitleElement>
        <TitleElementLevel>01</TitleElementLevel>
        <TitleText>This is the title I'm looking for</TitleText>
      </TitleElement>
    </TitleDetail>
  ...
</Product>
```

(It's [ONIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ONIX_(publishing_protocol)), if you're curious.)

I want to extract the title, of type 01.
I've tried:

```
say $dom->at('TitleDetail[TitleType="01"] > TitleElement > TitleText')
```

but that doesn't work.  Looks like the `tag[attr=value]` syntax really only works for attributes.

Is there a simple way to do what I want?

Comment: That was one mistake, yes, to use `/` instead of ` > ` as a tag separator...

Comment: `TitleDetail[TitleType="01"]` [means](http://mojolicious.org/perldoc/Mojo/DOM/CSS#SELECTORS) "*a `TitleDetail` element whose `TitleType` attribute value is exactly equal to `01`.*" Obviously incorrect. Unfortunately, you can't use a single call to `at` because subqueries are limited checking attributes, and none of the selectors provide a means of checking the text of a node.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It can be done with Mojo::DOM, but it's long. A couple of times there are Mojo::Collections in there, so you need to get the first element out.

```
use Mojo::DOM;

my $dom = Mojo::DOM->new->xml(1)->parse($xml);
say $dom->find("TitleType")->grep(sub{ $_->text eq "01"})->first
    ->following("TitleElement")->first->at("TitleText")->text;
```

Comment: Thanks!  I'll accept this answer if nothing better comes along soon.  But I won't be using it; XML::XPath turns out to be better in this case.

Comment: @mscha I agree that XML::XPath is better. It looks cleaner and it probably does less work to get the job done.

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps my problem is that I'm using a hammer to insert a screw...

I love Mojo::DOM and its simplicity, but perhaps it's not so well suited for parsing structured XML, and I should use XML::XPath:

```
my $xp = XML::XPath->new(xml=>$xml);
say $xp->findvalue('//TitleDetail[TitleType=01]/TitleElement/TitleText');
```

This does what I need.

Comment: Now just switch to XML::LibXML (or XML::Twig) and you have a power tool for any screw -- once you noted that you don't insist on the hammer :)

Comment: @zdim Not any screw...Mojo::DOM can handle HTML and malformed XML, while those modules can't. :P

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot  Right, thank you, should've said "perfect screw." Also, the point (with `XML::XPath`) seems to be to just go for `XPath`, so perhaps my comment is completely off.

Comment: @zdim, in this case I have a single record from which I have to extract just a handful of values, so `XML::XPath` will do just fine.  For parsing large feeds, `XML::LibXML` or `XML::Twig` are indeed better and I've used them both in the past.  Didn't like it, though – having to deal with namespaces in every single tag name, etc. – that's why I was looking at `Mojo::DOM` first.  But here, nobody bothered to specify a namespace so I didn't have to worry about that.  